# Factoring out a duplicated java 8 expression

Tags: java-8

I find myself duplicating over and over the same java 8 expression:

In one method, I have:

```
List<Message> latestMessages = new ArrayList<>();
...
return latestMessages.stream().map(messageMapper::asMessageDto).collect(toList());
```

Then in another method of the same class, I have:

```
List<Message> messagesBetweenTwoUserAccounts = ...;
return messagesBetweenTwoUserAccounts.stream().map(messageMapper::asMessageDto).collect(toList());
```

The return type of both methods is:  `List<MessageDto>`

I basically convert from a `List<Message>` to a `List<MessageDto>`.

Notice the duplicated expression:

**`stream().map(messageMapper::asMessageDto).collect(toList());`**

What would be the best way to factor out the above expression using java 8 constructs?

Comment: How is it specific to Java 8? You can write a single method that gets a `List<Message>` and returns `List<MessageDto>`. The fact that the body of the method contains Java 8 constructs makes no difference.

Comment: I thought there would be another java 8 construct for **mapping** and **collecting** but I might be wrong...

Comment: I'd probably won't do it, but technically you could create a `Function<List<Message>, List<MessageDto>> f  = l -> l.stream().map(messageMaper::asMessageDto).collect(toList());` and use it as `return f.apply(lastestMessages);`

Comment: You should focus. Do you want to know how to extract common code into a method or whether there is an alternative to that Stream API use? Questions starting with “What would be the best way …” generally get a negative reception. Well, question boiling down to “is there an alternative to …” are considered off-topic too.

Comment: @Alexis C.: what’s the advantage over an ordinary method?

Comment: No advantages (that's why I'm saying I won't do it), just giving another ''technical'' approach.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Alexis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to repeat the `latestMessages.stream().map(messageMapper::asMessageDto).collect(toList());` multiple times, write a method that contains it :

```
public static List<MessageDto> transformMessages (List<Message> messages) {
    return messages.stream().map(messageMapper::asMessageDto).collect(toList());
}
```

Now you can call it from multiple places without repeating that Stream pipeline code.

I don't know if that method should be static or not. That depends on where you are calling it from, and where `messageMapper` comes from (as Holger commented). You can add `messageMapper` as an argument if different invocations of the method require different mappers.

Comment: Well, it depends on where `messageMapper` does come from…

Comment: messageMapper is an instance field on the class.

Comment: I only use the `messageMapper` in that same class.